# How can I restrict my iOS Project to iPhone 4 Only

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I'm using a barcode scanner library within my iOS project that currently only supports iPhone 4 devices. Is it possible to restrict the application submission so that only iPhone 4 users can load it, is this a cause for rejection from the App Store?

Comment: Requires iOS 4.0+ on the device? Or requires iPhone 4 devices? Those are very different questions, with very different answers. (And if the latter, can you explain why, for example, a 3GS won't work?)

Comment: Do you mean iOS 4 or iPhone 4? *Edit: Otto beat me to it :)*

Comment: I did indeed mean iPhone 4. I'm using the ZBar Barcode library which has a known, as of yet unfixed crash bug with the 3GS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>gyroscope</string>
</array>
```

This will restrict it to only iPhones that have the gyroscope, which is iPhone4 and beyond.

Not sure this is the *best* way, but it should work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you're detecting an "iPhone 4" this is a great way to do it.  If you're wanting "iOS 4" see the answer by Allara.

Comment: Yup, agreed. Though I do wonder if Apple's review team will mind that it says "gyroscope" required when the app doesn't use the gyroscope..

Comment: I think he's more after the camera than for the gyro.

Comment: Or the AVFoundation, which means he's looking for iOS4. If it just the camera, he should set the above gyroscope value to whatever checks for a camera, with the iOS version set to 4+.

Comment: I am trying to target only iPhone 4 devices (due to a bug in the barcode library I'm using that causes crashes with the 3GS).

Answer (score 6):

In your Xcode target configuration, under the Deployment group, change the iOS Deployment Target to the desired version. This will not cause a rejection of your app.

Edit: The original question was ambiguous. This answer refers to how to restrict your app to iOS 4.

Comment: Best way.  Then it won't even show up on older devices on the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the **[UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html)** in the SDK. It is generally Apple's policy to try to make your app available to all devices. I can't remember off the top of my head if the App store will only show Apps that are made to work on the device or if the App store does a blanket view.