# How to Restrict the iOS app only for iPhone excluding iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I want to restrict my app only for iPhone. I don't want my app is available for  iPad.

Comment: a quick google - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718813/how-can-i-restrict-my-ios-project-to-iphone-4-only

Comment: Apple wants iPad users to have access to the full App Store, including iPhone apps. You can't disable that. The one partial solution you have is to detect on startup if the user is on iPad than display an alert about this program can't be used on iPad but I'm not sure Apple would let that solution into the App Store.

Comment: @Veeru, That's old (iPhone 4 times), my Retina iPad has a gyroscope.

Comment: Well then unfortunately i am out of ideas :) - as far as i remember, one of the apple's rules were that an app should be able to run an ipad(if not it would get rejected) even though it is build for iphone. Not sure if there are any new rules.

Comment: What's wrong with an iPad running your iPhone app? Are you worried the app will crash if it tries to access camera feature which isn't available on iPad 1?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**YES, yes, you CAN**, set the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities stating that the app requires telephony. This means it will only work on an iPhone. Please read more about it from the Apple Documentation here -

[UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities - setting conditions so app store knows which devices to allow installation on](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3)

Within this page, search for UIRequiredDeviceCapabilites and it will tell you more from there.

I hope this helps anyone with this issue

Comment: @JBest Did you figure this out?

Comment: @Sam I have had luck by explicitly stating that iPads are not able to perform certain tasks in the app, and that every build setting that limits the app to iPhones has been set. I sometimes have to repeat myself. It's a workaround though. My hope is that now that iPads are getting their own OS, this issue will resolve itself for many developers out there.

Comment: Most of the answers are incorrect. The accepted and upvoted answer is also incorrect. @NSnik answer is the correct one. If you your was released with iPad support then there is nothing to be done. If it hasn't then add the above key.

Answer (score 20):

You can't restrict an application to run on iPhone only in the normal way.The iOS is designed such a way that the iPhone apps will run on iPad in 1x resolution .

However if you really want to restrict your app to iPhone , **you can** achieve this by stating that the app requires feature telephony to work by specifying the same in **UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities** . This means it will only work on an iPhone.

Comment: I only supplied iPhone pictures in the App Store and set the Device in the Deployment Info to iPhone and mine is still downloadable on iPad. Where do you specify that it's for iPhone only in the store? I can't see anything.

Comment: So, if I publish in the way you say, will it be able to download on Ipad, or will it be restricted at the store level ??

Comment: and one more thing is, in itunesConnect, it asks to upload for screenshots as well, how to skip those IPad screenshots and submit the binary ? @JIthin

Comment: If you specify Telephony in UIRequiredDevice capabilities , it will work on iPhone only and won't list in store for iPad. You can also specify in itunesConnect and in your build settings , that the app is iPhone only, so that the iPad screenshots won't be necessary.

Comment: Can anyone verify that Apple would indeed allow this after revision? They accepted my Builds 5 times, my build was targeted for iPhone, but NOW they say it needs to support iPad, but the previous 5 builds that THEY ACCEPTED, do not support iPad..

Comment: @DaWiseguy: Same thing happened with my app. I have been submitting for over 4 years but this time they rejected it as it does not work on iPad. Were you able to submit iPhone only app ? Thanks.

Comment: @user4848830 I think our developer had to contact the Apple team as there was an error. In XCODE make sure you have your app selected for iPhone Only, and remove any AppIcons that are only utilized by the iPad. HOWEVER, I have seen this note today: Starting April, 2020, all iPhone and iPad apps submitted to the App Store will need to be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later. They must also support the all-screen design of iPhone XS Max or the 12.9-inch iPad Pro (3rd generation), or later. Not sure if it means iPad is required.

Comment: @user4848830 Depending on my understanding, you may NEED to support iPad icons, even if your app is set to iPhone only. Your app does not need to fully work on the iPad, however the app must at least look decent in case it is run on an iPad. The apple developers will check for design issues. Perhaps you have a constraint that does not look good on iPad, or an image that is too small for iPad.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot restrict permissions to install the application from the AppStore to iPhones only. If your application has already been added to the AppStore and had the ability to install on iPad, then you will not be able to set restrictions only for iPhones.

Even if you set **telephony yes** in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities. In this case, you will get an error loading build to the AppStore.

> **Important: Because you can't add UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities restrictions after an app is in the store, be sure to plan ahead by
>   choosing requirements you will be comfortable supporting indefinitely
>   going forward.**

If set **TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY iPhone**, apps will run in emulated mode in iPad

The only way is to add UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities, that allow installation on an iPhone/iPad, before to add app to the AppStore!

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable the iPad's ability to run your iPhone app.

Answer (score -1):

In your info.plist,   add the following:

```
<key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
<array>
  <integer>1</integer>
</array>
```

1 = iphone and ipod, 2 = ipad

Comment: 1 = ? and 2 = ?

Comment: 1 = ipad and ipod, 2 = ipad

Comment: iPhone-only apps can still be installed and run on iPads.