# Restrict app only for iPhone/iPod, not iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, info.plist

I would like to know if there is a Property to set in info.plist file so that the app could run only on iPhone or iPod, but not on iPad, so that App Store does not distribute the app to iPad users, even if the select the “iPhone” option.
An app designed for iPhone runs on iPad compatibility mode with the same screen size of 3.5” devices, and this is not enough for a proper display.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24974148/2019221

Comment: Actually it's not Possible. application can be downloaded from any device whether it's iPad or iPhone. How one can analyze from appstore whether it's ipad or iphone

Comment: It is a requirement that apps iPhone apps run on iPad at iPhone resolution. It is in the App Store approval requirements.