# Change compatibility of submitted app from universal to iPhone only

Tags: iphone, app-store, submit

My app that I submitted yesterday to the App Store had to be compatible only for iPhones because that is how I already set it to like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KECg0.jpg).

Now I saw that on iTunes on my app it says that is compatible with iPhone, iPad and iPod and it really should be only iPhone.

I tried to solve the problem with adding the element `telephony` to the array `Required device capabilities` in `info.plist` like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeNJR.jpg).

Will that make in iTunes to say `Compatible with iPhone only` and not allow installs on iPads and iPods ? If not how can I solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should do it according to this other stack overflow post:

[How to Restrict the iOS app only for iPhone excluding iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927716/how-to-restrict-the-ios-app-only-for-iphone-excluding-ipad)

Essentially there's no way to restrict apps by device unless the device doesn't have a feature you need, in this case, the ability to make calls (telephony).

Comment: Thank you and now what if I don't write anything in "What's new" when I submit the app ? Will it show up empty or It wouldn't show up at all ?