# Why Can I build my app on iPhone and iPad even set Devices for "iPhone" in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

In Xcode, I always set "iPhone" in Target->General->Development Info->Devices. I know when I want to launch the app on both of iPhone and iPad, I should set "Universal". But even I don't set that, the app works perfectly on both devices.

Then I don't know why it works well and when should I set "Universal"?

[image: setting image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Restrict the iOS app only for iPhone excluding iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927716/how-to-restrict-the-ios-app-only-for-iphone-excluding-ipad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I got your question, Now what happens for at Apple team side is even if you set it to

**iPhone** **only**, your app should not **hide any UI elements in the iPad** like the button is **cutting from bottom etc** your app will get **reject** if that happens, if you set it to iPhone only it can happen you will see a **black border on sides of iPad** but that is fine with Apple team only your view is **viewing properly on iPad**

Now if you set it to **Universal** its expected your view is supporting all iPads and iPhones.

Hope you find this answer **satisfactory**

Comment: Thank you for your answering. If I set it to "iPad" or "Universal", Do I have to set the app icon for iPad? Is this setting for only the viewing?

Answer (score 0):

iPhone only apps are designed specifically for the iPhone. These apps can still run on the iPad.  However, they will run in iPhone compatibility mode. But you can't disable the iPad's ability to run your iPhone app.