# How to Restrict the React native iOS app only for iPhone excluding iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native

I want my React native app only for iPhone, not for iPad.I submit my app to the App store. but it rejects.they check my app on iPad device. it has some design issue. but my app only build for iphone. how to restrict that.

I used xcode Version 15.0.1 . and React Native version 0.71.8.
And also i set "Targeted Device Families" to "iPhone"
and my info.plist file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>halofoto</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.22.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.988154087943-021kt591c3mjjrv64a9fd0rtba95qt98</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>4</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true />
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true />
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to use the camera. Halofoto would like to access your camera to enable you to scan and capture photos within the app. This feature allows you to personalize your experience by adding images for your profile and for the new products registered by you in this app. Your privacy is important to us, and we will only use the camera for its intended purpose. Tap 'Allow' to grant camera access. Our app adheres to privacy guidelines and only requests permissions necessary for its core features.</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Give $(PRODUCT_NAME) permission to access your location.Halofoto would like to access your location for shipping the product.</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your microphone</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Give $(PRODUCT_NAME) permission to save photos. Halofoto would like to save the photos for the profile section of user and to show the listing of the products registered by user. Your privacy is important to us, and we will only use the camera for its intended purpose.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Give $(PRODUCT_NAME) permission to access your photos. Halofoto would like to access your photos for uploading the profile photos of user and to show the listing of the products registered by user. Your privacy is important to us, and we will only use the camera for its intended purpose.</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>SplashScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <true />
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false />
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927716/how-to-restrict-the-ios-app-only-for-iphone-excluding-ipad) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Restrict the iOS app only for iPhone excluding iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927716/how-to-restrict-the-ios-app-only-for-iphone-excluding-ipad)